# Mahout FPG algorithm Always uses single reducer

Tags: machine-learning, mahout

I'm using [Mahout (v 0.7) parallel FPG algorithm](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Parallel+Frequent+Pattern+Mining), CLI mode, to generate frequent patterns.  The algorithm works fine and generates the frequent patterns correctly.

The problem I'm having is that the algorithm always uses one reducer in the second stage of generating the patterns.  The algorithm creates one mapper for each input split, but in the second stage, all the mappers send their output to one reducer which significantly slows down the algorithm.

I even tried to set the `-Dmapred.reduce.tasks` parameter to override the default number of reducers, and it did not work.

I would like to split the work of the second stage to multiple reducers, if possible.

Mahout's FPG command I use:

```
 mahout fpg \
     -i /path/to/input \
     -o /path/to/output \
     -s 5 \
     -k 100 \
     -method mapreduce
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of mappers and reducers by adding this at the end of your command:

```
 -Dmapred.map.tasks=1000 -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1000
```

For me, I couldn't change the number of mappers with this parameter, but I was always able to control the number of reducers.

Comment: I added the parameter `-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=18` at the end of the command and tried different numbers of reducers and didn't work.

Comment: I can only guess that it is designed like that everything to goes into one reducer. I had the same problem with RowSimilarityJob, where the number of mappers was always 175., but I thought you can control the number of reducers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your data currently fits into a single mapper split.

You can make the split size smaller with something like:

```
-Dmapred.max.split.size=1048576
```

(That would reduce the split size to 1024*1024==1MB, but I've gone even smaller with Mahout before, such as `-Dmapred.max.split.size=131072` for 128KB splits on very CPU-intensive jobs.)